# Django: Form Instance Not loading

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm using a view to load objects onto the form .I'm using [Material Form Library](http://forms.viewflow.io/)

I have added **CKEditor** on the form through Jquery, the form is saved but I cannot seem to load the data onto the form.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^viewprescription/(?P<tid>\d+)/$', views.get_template, name='viewtemplates'),
```

**views.py**

```
def get_template(request, tid):
    template = presciptiontemplates.objects.get(templateid=tid)
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = templateform(request.GET, instance=template)
        messages.success(request, 'Prescription loaded')
        print(form)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            Presciptiontemplates = presciptiontemplates()
            Presciptiontemplates.savedate = datetime.now()
            Presciptiontemplates.template = form.cleaned_data.get('template')
            Presciptiontemplates.draft = form.cleaned_data.get('draft')
            Presciptiontemplates.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Prescription Saved Successfully')
    else:
        form = templateform(request.GET, instance=template)
        messages.error(request, 'Please Try Again')
        print(form)
    return render(request, 'presapp/viewtemplate.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class templateform(forms.ModelForm):
    template = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='')
    draft = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    layout = Layout(Fieldset('Template'), ('template'), ('draft'))

    class Meta:
        model = presciptiontemplates
        fields = ['template', 'draft']
```

**models.py**

```
class presciptiontemplates(models.Model):
    templateid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    template = RichTextField()
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    savedate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    patientid=models.IntegerField()
```

**viewtemplate.html**

```
<div id="preview-content">
  <form method="POST" style="margin-top:20px;">
    {% csrf_token %}
     {% form %} 
    {% endform %}
    <div class="" style="margin-top:20px ;">
      <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light left" type="submit">Submit
    <i class="material-icons right">add_circle</i>
    </button>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are lots of strange things here - especially your capitalisation - but we can't see what is actually wrong without seeing your template.

Comment: Where are those `{% form %}` and `{% endform %}` tags coming from?

Comment: Its as per the documentation in django-material-forms (http://docs.viewflow.io/material_forms.html)

Comment: Your view doesn't seem to be structured properly. Your form uses POST method, but you're handling form validation inside the GET block.

Comment: @CODEkid the request i get is in GET, I had been changing the request type in the code , still doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your form template tag the form from the view context ie:

```
{% form form=form %}{% endform %}
```

That's what it states in the quickstart from the documentation: http://forms.viewflow.io/

Comment: Changed the code, the form instance is still not loading

Comment: Did you include {% load material_form %} at the beginning of your template?

Comment: Yes, I used the tag in the {% block content  %}